# Inputting a line of characters

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a problem of inputting a line of characters to an array. Here's the main problem. I've declared an array of size 50 lets say and i want to input my name but when I've inputed it using a loop it wont store it the loop just continues to run until I've typed till 50 characters :/
How can I avoid this problem?
Explain with an example thanks :)

```
           void option1()//here user inputs the data
        {
         string name[20];
         string date[20];
         string from[20];
         string to[20];
         string id_no[20];



        system("CLS");
        cout << "\n\n\t\tEnter your seat no.:  ";
        cin >> seat;

        while(seat>32 || seat<0)
        {
            cout << "\n\t\tThere are no seats greater than 32 please type in again: ";
            cin >> seat;
        }
        cout << "\t\tEnter your name: ";
        cin >> name[seat];

        cout << "\t\tEnter Your date: ";
        cin >> date[seat];

        cout << "\t\tEnter your ID No. :";
        cin >> id_no[seat];

        cout << "\t\tWhere do you want to travel:\n ";

        cout << "\t\t\tFrom: ";
        cin >> from[seat];

        cout << "\t\t\tTo: ";
        cin >> to[seat];

        system("CLS");

        cout << "\n\n\t\tTHANK YOU! YOUR SEAT HAS BEEN BOOKED\n";
        getchar();
        system("CLS");
        }
      void option2()//From here how can i bring the data to this funciton?
   {
       string name[20];
       string date[20];
       string from[20];
       string to[20];
       string id_no[20];
      cout << "\t\t\tEnter your seat number: ";
      cin >> seat;

        cout << "\t\tYour Name: " << name[seat] << endl;

        cout << "\t\tYour Date of travelling: " << date[seat] << endl;

       cout << "\t\tYour ID no. : " << id_no[seat] << endl;

       cout << "\t\tTravelling From: " << from[seat] << endl;

       cout << "\t\tTravelling To: " << to[seat] << endl;
```

}

Comment: Show what you've attempted.

Comment: No, edit your question, and show your code as part of the question.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Sorry I'm new at this :'3

Comment: That's fine, but you also need to indent and format your code correctly. Your code looks ugly. Proper indentation is required in order for your code to be readable. If you want to encourage people to help you, you should make your code readable, and easy to understand.

Comment: Have you considered following a conventional tutorial, which would show you how to input and output a `std::string`?  What led you to try writing it this way?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks sir I'll make sure to be careful in the future now to remove my confusion please.

Comment: Don't follow a "conventional tutorial". Pick up a good book and study.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing this the wrong way.

Use C++ `std::string`s instead.

```
std::string name, id;

std::cin >> name >> id; // so easy!
```

If your `id`s aren't very long and contain only numbers, you may read them into numbers:

```
unsigned long id;

std::cin >> id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the problem by using the `std::string` class:

```
std::string name;
std::cout << "Enter name: ";
std::getline(std::cin, name);
```

If you must need to use an array of characters, you can use `getline`:

```
#define MAX_NAME_LENGTH 50
char array[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
cin.getline(&array[0], MAX_NAME_LENGTH, '\n');
```

There are many issues you will be running into if you use arrays of characters.  The preferred method is to use `std::string`.  For example, `std::string` manages the memory (allocation & deleting), as well as expanding on demand.  You only need to pass `std::string` to a function because it has a `length` member function.  With arrays, you need to pass the array, capacity and size.  By the way, if you don't maintain the '\0' terminating character in the array, undefined behavior results.